# Check If a string exists in a text document

Tags: autohotkey

I have a text document with multiple strings in it,
Example:

```
Enabled
Start
Mark
David
Dylan
```

Now what I'm having troubles with is getting auto-hotkey to read the text document and see if it exists and IF it exists have it select an option on a program. So if it exists it will go click a button on my application. How would I go of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Loop, Read` from the docs: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm

```
Loop, Read, file.txt
{
    line := A_LoopReadLine
    if (line == "David") {
        ; do something because David was found.
        MsgBox, % "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that."
    } 
}
```